# 2000s Anthology book with a man who plays a real version of a video game that his clone “son” plays as a video game

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

It was a collection of Sci-fi stories, one was about a boy who was really good at a kind of video game. There was a man who played a real version of the game where injury/loss of limb/death was a possibility, and everytime this man fought, the kids mum got really worried and wouldn't let him watch. Eventually this kid figures out he's the man's clone, then the man's son (who is also a clone) loses his legs (I think) in a skiiing accident and the kid wakes up with no legs. Another was about a boy who was interviewing his grandad about the past (our present) and blames the grandads "stories" about the past on his dementia. I read it, most likely, in the early 2000's.

Comment: Can you remember any other details that might assist? For example: When did you read this? Do you remember the cover at all? Can you remember any specific details from the grandfather's stories that were not believed by the boy? Do you recall anything about any of the other stories? Male or female authors? Famous or obscure authors? Was the collection themed or a "best of" or anything like that?

Comment: I think i read it early 2000s, cover may have been blue, most likely obscure authors, there was possibly something about a group of students going to a TV like studio on a bus? But none of them had seen a car or bus before, unfortunately I only have vague memories of the book, otherwise I may have been able to remember more